# python logic to extract pattern of strings in list

Tags: python, list, loops, conditional-statements, logic

```
text =  [('Automated', 'PROPN'), ('Unit', 'PROPN'), ('testing', 'NOUN'), ('design', 'NOUN'), ('and', 'CCONJ'), ('implementation', 'NOUN'), ('experience', 'NOUN')]

pattern  =['NOUN', 'CCONJ', 'NOUN', 'NOUN']
```

#program should extract   =>>>>    design and implementation experience
#can be done using regex or list methods or string methods

```
'''
def get_matched(text,patterns):   # patterns => list of cases
    punctuations = ''',-''' 
    s = ""
    for char in text:
      if char not in punctuations:
          s = s + char
    if "/" in s :     # replacing "/"  with or because "/" is recognised as symbol in pos tags
      s = s.replace('/', ' or ')
    res = re.sub(' +', ' ', s)        
    doc = nlp(res)
    words = []
    for case in patterns:
          matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab) 
          matcher.add("matching_1",[case[1::]]) 
          matches = matcher(doc) 
          for match_id,start,end in matches:
                span = doc[start:end]
                l =  span.text.split()
                if len(l)  > 0 :
                  #print(l)
                  index =  case[0]
                  try:
                    for i in range (len(index)):
                      temp = ""
                      for ind in index[i]:
                          temp =  temp  + l[ind] + " "
                      words.append(temp)
                    words.append(' '.join(l),text)
                    print("->>>>>>>>>>>",text)
                  except:
                    print(case,l)
                    
    return words

'''
```

1. i i done it with sapcy matching but i have toi write logic for it

Comment: Looks like a homework question. Please post your genuine effort in solving this.

Comment: no actually it is one of my nlp case wait let me comment entire preperation

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = ""
for i in pos_tags:
        temp =  temp  +i 
for i in cases: 
    case  = ''.join(i[0])
    if temp.find(case) > 0:
        case_lenght = len(i[0])
        for ind in range(len(pos_tags)-(case_lenght-1)):
            if pos_tags[ind:(case_lenght+ind)] == i[0]:
                extracted_sent = text[ind:ind+case_lenght]
                for tuple in i[1]:
                    word = ""
                    for index in tuple:
                        word =  word + " " + text[index]
                    print(word)
```